# All options not being populated by ng-options

Tags: angularjs

In this codepen I'm attemptling to load a option element from a scoped variable :

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>AngularJS test</title>
</head>

<body ng-app ng-controller="TestCtrl">


  <select ng-init="vendor = vendors[0]" ng-model="vendor" ng-options="vendorName as vendor.name for vendorName in vendors"></select>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>


function TestCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.vendors = [{
    name: 'Oracle1',
    name: 'Oracle2'
  }];

}
```

But just the element at position[1] is being loaded.

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVbXJV?editors=101

Why is just 1 option element being loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an array of objects not just one object containing multiple names.

```
$scope.vendors = [
    {name: 'Oracle1'},
    {name: 'Oracle2'}
];
```

You can then use `ng-options` like so:

```
ng-options="vendor.name for vendor in vendors"
```